# Waiting in a loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, cocos2d-iphone

I have a game where you have a sprite that shoots a bullet. I have created a `for` loop that updates the y position of the bullet sprite.

```
for(int x=0; x<capacity; x++){
int bulletY = 100;
[bullet setPosition:ccp(sniper.position.x, bulletY)];
bulletY = bulletY + addition;
}
```

But this does it almost instantaneously. I want to show the bullet moving. I was thinking at the end of the loop 
I could have a wait but I can't use

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5f 
                                 target:self
             selector: @selector(doSomething:) 
                           userInfo:nil
                            repeats:NO];
```

because I don't have a selector. And I can't use `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0f];` because it doesn't show the bullet moving.

So how could I delay it a bit without using the above?

Comment: You are going to need some kind of time system for the whole game in which you update and draw sprites accordingly.

Comment: why don't use a helper method and call it with it selector?

Comment: Go read about actions in Cocos2D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare int bulletY; as instance variable in your .h file. Make new update method

```
-(void) myUpdate:(ccTime)dt
{
    bulletY++;

    [bullet setPosition:ccp(sniper.position.x, bulletY)];

}
```

Call your new method like this, maybe from init.

```
[self schedule:@selector(myUpdate:) interval:1.0f]; //1.0f is once per second, change it
```